# Creating nested JSON in R

Tags: json, r, nested

I have data in a CSV file that looks like

```
1,2, Child
1,3, Child
1,4, Child
3,5, Child
5,6, Child
```

I want to convert it to a JSON that looks like

```
{
    "id": "1",
    groups: [{
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            groups: [{
                "id": "5",
                groups: [{
                    "id": "6"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am new to R and have looked at Lists and the `toJSON` and `fromJSON` from the `rjson` package. I am not able to figure out how to go more than 2 levels while creating the json.

If someone could give me an idea to go about it or a better data structure to handle this, I would really appreciate it

Comment: your csv is missing a comma and your json is missing quotes around groups

Comment: If you're "new to R" you might want to spend some time working with R before tackling this data transformation by asking others to code it for you on SO.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like it needs a bit of pre-processing before it can be jsoned.

Comment: My original approach was to convert from list to JSON. So my code is similar to this
 a=list("id"="5",groups=c("6"))
 b=list("id"="3",groups=a)
 c=list("id"="1",groups=c("2",b,"4"))
cat(toJSON(c))
So my output for this looks like
{"id":"1","groups":{"":"2","id":"3","groups":{"id":"5","groups":"6"},"":"4"}}
My problem with this approach is that the 2,3,4 array looks like an object and I am not able to get a "id" tag around 2 and 4. Please advice